# How to detect drive letters which are assigned twice?

Tags: c, windows, drive-letter

There is a small bug in Windows that I would like to create a small application as a solution for. So, in my company we have several network drives ( F:\, G:\, H:\, I:\ etc.) and sometimes if I connect an external USB device such as a card reader, windows will assign an already used drive letter. So for example, I have a network drive F:\, and I connect my card reader which windows will also assign F:\ to this device, so I cant use that USB device, until I change it's drive letter.

So my question's are:

- How can I detect these devices or drive letters when they are assigned twice?
- How can I detect which one of them is a USB device?
- How can I reassign a drive letter to that device?

I want to do this in C.

Thanks.

Comment: Admin issue -- redirecting.

Comment: @pst What do you mean with admin issue? I just want to know how to get those drive letters which are assigned twice.

Comment: What pst probably meant is that [you can manually change the drive letter assignment](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-add-or-remove-a-drive-letter). Surely it's quicker to reassign letters yourself than having to write up a program for such an extremely specific situation that you need to test.

Comment: @In silico - i know that, but the reason i want to create an application for this is, that a user cannot change it manually becasue they are not administrators, and that's why i want to make an application, so they can change it too.

Comment: @In silico: i know that too, but this is my problem. I will use CreateProcessWitLogonW for this, and then the users can use this application too.

Comment: @kampi: Ah, okay. That's fine.

Comment: I've run into this problem, and it's rather irritating. Let us know if you're successful.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, that's why i want to make this application. It irritates me, too. I don't understand, why Microsoft can't solve this issue. If i find a solution then i will wirte you

Comment: IIRC, you can use `DISKPART` to do this (it has an `ASSIGN` command to assign drive letters and mount points).

Comment: This bug was fixed in Vista and Windows 7. You must be using XP?

Comment: @Breakthrough yes, i know that, but if it possible, i don't want to use an external application. If it is possible i want do this in C

Comment: @Moab: Yes, we are using Windows XP...for now :)

Comment: @kampi without Diskpart (which is included with all versions of Windows), you'll need to find the proper Windows API calls.  I don't know why this was migrated from Stack Overflow to be honest, since you want to write this in C it's most fitting over there.  Either way, start with the [volume management reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from the MSDN.  There should be more then enough information to get you started from there.

Comment: I always have the habit of assigning network drive letters at the end of the alphabet, Z, X, Y etc, this prevents these problems in XP.

Comment: @Breakthrough: yes, this is what i need, the proper Windows APIs. Necrolis already posted some APIs from Volume Managament right now i'm trying to use them :) I also don't know why this question was migrated, and who or why migrated this question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Moab: Yes, you are right, but every department has their own drive letters. So it is possible, that the IT department has x,y,z drives, and another department hasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most of what you want can be done with [`FindFirstVolume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364425%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and its friends (the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542456%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) covers everything), to get the type, you would use [`GetDriveType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then finally [`SetVolumeMountPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365561(v=VS.85).aspx) will rename a device drive letter.

Comment: SetVolumeLabel will just change the label of the drive not the assigned drive letter.

Comment: @RedX: correct, fixed

Comment: Well, this is awkward. Question came from StackOverflow, was properly answered by recommending the appropriate API functions and was then later migrated to SuperUser for no good reason. Even states the user wants to do it in C.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: your are right. I didn't either understand why it was migrated....

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Hmmm, this is indeed awkward :| well so long as it stays helpful as an answer.