# How to make sure Windows (7) does update names of drives?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, sd-card, drive-letter

The issue: I have two network drives set up, that are however not always connected. When they are not connected, and I connect a usb drive or insert an sd card, often these drives/cards will not show up under a new drive letter, with their own name, but under the drive letter and the name of the network drive. Of course most of the time things still work when you just click on the network drive anyway, but it is quite irritating and just seems like there is something wrong.

Edit: This is also more or less described here: [How to detect drive letters which are assigned twice?](https://superuser.com/questions/327353/how-to-detect-drive-letters-which-are-assigned-twice) but there the poster asked about how to program a solution (which I do not want) and there were no satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

Instead of using drive letters mount your SD-Card and USB-Drive each on a directory of its own. So you may avoid duplicate drive letters with network drives.